# How to respond to command questions on a CLI using pexpect?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-interface, pexpect

I am using Python and pexpect to automate a CLI interface for a networking device.
The problem is that I cannot use pexpect to send commands that require "yes"/"no" confirmation. 
I think this happens because pexpect does not match the question.

```
child = pexpect.spawn ('ssh -p <port> user@192.168.1.1')
child.expect ("password: ")
child.sendline ('userPass')
child.expect ('> ')
child.sendline('show')
child.expect('> ')
logging.info(child.before)

# works fine untill now - it connects to the box and prints the show output

child.sendline ('reset')

logging.info(child.before)
# this command prints the same thing as previous child.before

logging.info('This line gets printed.')

child.expect ("<additional text> Are You sure? [no,yes] ")

logging.info('This line does not get printed.')

child.sendline ('yes')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After escaping the expected text, the "yes" was still not accepted/sent to device.
I fixed the issue by sending and additional line ('') after "yes":

```
child.sendline ('yes')
child.sendline('')
```

Comment: there are several issues in your code in the question. You should try to limit your questions to one issue per question (i.e., try to localize your issue first). Otherwise, *each* answer should address all issues (it is not a traditional forum). I suspect your code needs `child.expect(pexpect.EOF); child.close()` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import re

child.expect( re.escape("<additional text> Are You sure? [no,yes] ") )
```

I think (but didn't check the documentation now) that pexpect handles the text as a regular expression.  That is useful for matching things that aren't necessarily a constant.  However, it does mean that when you want to match characters that have meaning in the regular expression grammar (eg '?', '[', and ']') then you need to escape them accordingly.

Comment: Yes, adding adding the escape resulted in a successfull match of the text. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`[]?` are regex meta characters (they have special meaning and are not matched literally). To avoid interpreting the pattern as a regular expression, use [`child.expect_exact(your_pattern)`](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.expect_exact) instead.